# How I can post reviews on a facebook page through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The scenario is I want a Facebook widget or an API that enables user on my site to post reviews on my Facebook page. Is FB provides any plugin or API that I can integrate to my site where user logins to Facebook and post reviews on a page without leaving my site.
Note: I am successful in getting all the ratings on my page through Facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is FB provides any plugin or API that I can integrate to my site where user logins to Facebook and post reviews on a page without leaving my site.

No, there is no such thing.

(The abuse potential would probably be massive – “fake” reviews are a big problem for all other platforms already, Amazon, Yelp, etc. So don’t expect Facebook to make posting reviews via API possible any time soon, I very much doubt they’d have any interest in that.)

Comment: so what is the way around this, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can’t, simple as that. If people want to leave a review on your Facebook page, then they need to go and visit your Facebook page.